# Prove $f(z)=\frac{z}{1+|z|}$ is a homeomorphism

Tags: complex-analysis

$f:\Bbb C \to D(0,1)$ defined by $f(z)=\frac{z}{1+|z|}$

I want to show that $f$ is a homeomorphism, but I’m stuck when I prove that $f$ is injective.

If $f(z)=f(w)$, then $|z|=|w|$, but how can I show that $z=w$?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you already know that $\frac{z}{1+\lvert z\rvert}=\frac{w}{1+\lvert w\rvert}$ implies $\lvert z\rvert=\lvert w\rvert$, you can multiply both sides by $1+\lvert z\rvert$ and obtain $z=w$.